# Facebook JS SDK in IE 8/7 issues

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently in the process of developing a Facebook canvas app and have come across an issue that I cant seem to fix with IE8/7 and the JS SDK

I am trying to test the current status of the user e.g connected, not authorised. and this works fine in Chrome, Firefox but it does not seem to be firing in IE. Here is my Facebook JS code

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    channelUrl : '//www.mydomain.co.uk/channel.html', // Channel File
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true,
    status: true
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

    if (response.status === 'connected'){
        alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);

        $('a#remove-app').click(function(){

        //var request = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        //console.log(request);

            $("#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog( "destroy" );

        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                position: [236,101],
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function() {

                        if(request){
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'get',
                                dataType: 'jsonp',
                                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions',
                                data: 'method=delete&access_token=' + request,
                                success: function(response) {
                                    top.location.href = 'http://facebook.com';
                                }

                            });

                        }

                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });


            return false;
    }); 

    } else if( response.status === 'not_authorized') {

        var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
            oauth_url += '?client_id=xxxxxxxxx';
            oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/kaplan-acca-news/');
            oauth_url += '&scope=email'
        window.top.location = oauth_url;



    } else {

        //alert('user not logged in');
      var oauth_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/';
               oauth_url += '?client_id=xxxxxxxx';
               oauth_url += '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent('https://apps.facebook.com/kaplan-acca-news/');
               oauth_url += '&scope=email'
             window.top.location = oauth_url;   
    }

}, true);


$('a#invite-a-friend').click(function(){
    sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector();
});


// Multi friend selector for Facebook
function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {

        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
           message: 'Come and join the app on Facebook',
        });

}

function requestCallback(response) {
    alert(response);            
}   

};
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Any ideas on fixing this issue, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Run your JavaScript code through a 'JavaScript Lint' tool. You might have some minor JS errors in your code that Chrome / FF ignores, but IE doesn't like.

Comment: I have ran it through JS Lint and now have it working on IE 8 on Windows 7 but not Windows XP, any ideas why they would operate differently on the different versions of Windows?

Comment: They might for compatibility reasons. Try enabling / disabling IE7 compatibility mode.